# How do I check whether `lwp-download` worked correctly?

Tags: perl, lwp

I don't know anything about Perl but I urgently need to modify a Perl script. At some point it's downloading an about 500MB file from a server using `system("lwp-download $HttpPath $Out");`.

Is there any way I can find out if the downloading process went correctly, e.g. check whether downloaded file has the same size as the original one?

Thanks

Comment: by any chance do you control the server... or does the server provide checksums of files?

Comment: No. I just have the file's path.

Comment: I think the server has to provide a 'range' in http for you to check the size. but the only real way to validate that it went correctly is to check a checksum... but if there's no authoritative source checksum...

Comment: Just reading the answers I totally missed you were running lwp-download and not using the API if you're going to do that why not use something more robust like wget, curl, or aria2?

Comment: Well. I guess you're right. I didn't know about these alternatives. It turned out that I could check the file's integrity in the next step which was unzipping. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a dumb thing to shell out from your Perl program to run `lwp-download`, another Perl program. Just replace that call with the [`mirror` API from `LWP::Simple`](http://p3rl.org/LWP::Simple) and you get decent error reporting, directly there in your program instead of messing with exit codes.

Should you need even better/fine-grained error checking, [`mirror` from `LWP::UserAgent`](http://p3rl.org/LWP::UserAgent) is available, too.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the `system` command returns<sup>*</sup> the exit status of the program that it was running. By convention a return value of zero means success, and non-zero means some sort of error.

A typical idiom is something like

```
my $status = system($command);
if ($status == 0) {
    # the program succeeded ...
} else {
    # the program failed ...
    warn "The program failed. Status = ", $status>>8, "\n";
}
```

<sup>*</sup> - sort of, see [`perldoc -f system`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlfunc#system) for details

Comment: rule - but will "lwp-download" provide meaningful exit status to satisfy the OP's needs?

Comment: If the most important thing to know is whether the download was successful, then there's a 99% chance that the answer is yes.

Comment: visual inspection of the lwp-download source shows a couple of places where it will fail but provide a 0 exit status :(  It seems to use 0 to mean *some* data was successfully read.

Comment: This was general advice to apply to most uses of system, without addressing how it applies specifically to lwp-download, and which I never heard about until today. But the one place lwp-download can exit 0 without transferring a file is when the new file would clobber an existing file and the user does not/cannot give permission for that operation. By convention, applications should exit zero for success/non-zero for failure. Yes, from time to time you will get bitten in the ass using a program that doesn't follow convention. For the OP that doesn't know Perl, that's a lot better than nothing.